# Does Serverless or AWS NodeJS SDK require HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm trying to use [serverless-dynamodb-local](https://github.com/99x/serverless-dynamodb-local), but I get a NetworkError when it runs.  I've narrowed the issue down to when the plugin migrates my tables into the local DB upon startup.  It fails on the `createTable` command with the following error:

```
NetworkingError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:": DynamoDB - Error - 
 
 Networking Error ----------------------------------------

  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"
      at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:144:11)
      at Object.request (http.js:44:10)
      at features.constructor.handleRequest ($root\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\http\node.js:45:23)
      at executeSend ($root\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:348:29)
...
      at Request.callListeners ($root\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
      at Timeout.callNextListener [as _onTimeout] ($root\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:96:12) 
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

I wrote this test script to be run while DynamoDB local is running in a separate command window.  This script runs successfully every time, including creating the table!

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000',
  region: 'localhost',
  accessKeyId: 'DEFAULT_ACCESS_KEY', // needed if you don't have aws credentials at all in env
  secretAccessKey: 'DEFAULT_SECRET', // needed if you don't have aws credentials at all in env
});

async function main() {
  try {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(dynamo.endpoint, null, 2)}`);
    const tables = await dynamo.listTables().promise();
    console.log(`Tables:`, JSON.stringify(tables, null, 2));

    var params = {
      AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
          AttributeName: 'Artist',
          AttributeType: 'S',
        },
        {
          AttributeName: 'SongTitle',
          AttributeType: 'S',
        },
      ],
      KeySchema: [
        {
          AttributeName: 'Artist',
          KeyType: 'HASH',
        },
        {
          AttributeName: 'SongTitle',
          KeyType: 'RANGE',
        },
      ],
      ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5,
      },
      TableName: 'Music',
    };
    const tableData = await dynamo.createTable(params).promise();
    console.log('Created table', JSON.stringify(tableData, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Unexpected error!`, err);
  }
}

main();
```

Since the code in my test script is essentially the same as that in the Serverless plugin, I don't understand what could be causing the issue.  Is there something about how either Serverless or AWS SDK is started that expects https?  See also [this Github issue](https://github.com/99x/serverless-dynamodb-local/issues/264).

### UPDATE

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "serverless dynamodb install && serverless offline start"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.407.0",
    "serverless": "^2.31.0",
    "serverless-dynamodb-client": "^0.0.2",
    "serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.39",
    "serverless-offline": "^6.9.0"
  }
}
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service: dynamodb-local-test

frameworkVersion: ">=2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2

plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  dynamodb:
    stages:
      - dev
    start:
      port: 8000
      inMemory: true
      migrate: true
      seed: true
    seed:
      dev:
        sources:
          - table: Users
            sources: [seed-data/Users.json] 
          - table: Tweets
            sources: [seed-data/Tweets.json]

resources:
  Resources:
    UserTable:
      Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
      Properties:
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: handle
            KeyType: HASH
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: handle
            AttributeType: S
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 10
          WriteCapacityUnits: 10
        TableName: "Users"

    TweetsTable:
      Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
      Properties:
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: tweet_id
            KeyType: HASH
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: tweet_id
            AttributeType: S
          -
            AttributeName: handle
            AttributeType: S
          -
            AttributeName: retweet_count
            AttributeType: N
          -
            AttributeName: created_at
            AttributeType: S
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 10
          WriteCapacityUnits: 10
        TableName: "Tweets"
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          -
            IndexName: top-index
            KeySchema:
              -
                AttributeName: handle
                KeyType: HASH
              -
                AttributeName: retweet_count
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 50
              WriteCapacityUnits: 50
          -
            IndexName: tweet-index
            KeySchema:
              -
                AttributeName: handle
                KeyType: HASH
              -
                AttributeName: created_at
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 50
              WriteCapacityUnits: 50
```

### UPDATE

I was temporarily no longer having the issue, but I'm not sure why.  Also, after a few more hours, and on another project, I had the issue again.  I tried changing the following two things:

1. I disconnected from my company's VPN.
2. I updated the `aws-sdk` package from ^2.407.0 to ^2.875.0.

However, after seeing that dynamodb-local was now starting, migrating, and seeding, I reverted both of these changes to test whether that was the issue.  I also cleared the local `.dynamodb` folder.  Neither of these three changes caused the plugin to fail again.  I was even able to connect the local dynamodb instance to a local appsync instance, too.

Could there be a race condition between the plugin and the local DynamoDB instance?

Comment: Provide your `serverless.yml`, I want to see plugins block.

Comment: Added package.json and serverless.yml files.